# Cointegration: Testing for bounds in VAR and interpretation of results

Tags: r, regression, var

I am currently working with different pairwise VAR models to analyze cointegration relationships.

There is following pair of time series: X is I(0), Y I(1). Because X and Y are not integrated of same order (i.e. I(1) and I(1)), I can't carry out the Johansen and Juselius (`ca.jo`) test with the *vars* package. Rather, I have to consider a test by Pesaran et al. (2001) that works for time series that are integrated of different order.

Here is my reproducible code for a cointegration test of variables of different order of integration with a package named *ardl*:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("fcbarbi/ardl")
library(ardl)

data(br_month)
br_month

m1 <- ardl(mpr~cpi, data=br_month, ylag=1, case=3)
bounds.test(m1)

m2 <- ardl(cpi~mpr, data=br_month, ylag=1, case=3)
bounds.test(m2)
```

**Question here:** 
Can I test the cointegration of a VAR (with 2 variables) with the ARDL test?

**Interpretation of results (case 5 = constant+trend):**

```
bounds.test(m1)
PSS case 5  ( unrestricted intercept, unrestricted trend )
Null hypothesis (H0): No long-run relation exist, ie H0:pi=0

         I(0)   I(1)
  10%   5.59  6.26
   5%   6.56  7.30
   1%   8.74  9.63

F statistic  11.21852 
Existence of a Long Term relation is not rejected at 5%.


bounds.test(m2)
PSS case 5  (unrestricted intercept, unrestricted trend )
Null hypothesis (H0): No long-run relation exist, ie H0:pi=0

         I(0)   I(1)
  10%   5.59  6.26
   5%   6.56  7.30
   1%   8.74  9.63
F statistic  5.571511
```

Existence of a Long Term relation is rejected at 5% (even assumming all regressors I(0))

I would conclude that there ***is*** a cointegration relationship between cpi and mpr as the F statistic for `m2` is smaller than the critical value for I(0) at the 5% level.

**However, does it tell me anything that it can be concluded for `m2` but not `m1`?**

Answer (score 0):

To me, you are confusing the definition of "cointegration". Because: for many time series to be cointegrated, they **must** have the same order of integration.

So, your question rather seems to be "*what can I do when I have time series with different order of integration?*".

So, in that case, I would advise you to take differences (of non-stationary variables) to obtain stationarity; and leave stationary ones as they are. Then apply VAR ordinarily.

From ARDL test's 2001 paper: *This paper proposes a new approach to testing for the existence of a relationship between variables in levels which is applicable irrespective of whether the underlying regressors are purely I(0), purely I(1) or mutually cointegrated.*

So, normally, ARDL test is not used for cointegration checking.

Comment: Assume that both time series are I(0), i.e. trend-stationary at level: Can time series data be cointegrated then?

Comment: @Fanny, cointegration is a concept for non-stationary series. There is no way two stationary series be cointegrated! Look at def'n of cointegration carefully. When two stationary series co-move together in the long term, there is already no non-stationarity at hand.

Comment: @RichardHardy Found this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213578/testing-for-cointegration-and-building-a-vec-model "The first rank that you cannot reject is the number of cointegrating vectors. If you can reject all of them, all of your series appear to be stationary." So if I apply the ca.jo test to a pair of two I(0) time series, and I reject both r=0 and r=1, then I assume this is additional confirmation of true stationarity of my time series?

Comment: If you have two I(0) series, then there is already no cointegration. I(0) variables may co-move together. I(1) variables may co-move together. But, only in the case of the latter, we say, there is cointegration. Co-movement of  I(0) variables are not called cointegration. If you had grantueed your variables are I(0) (via Augmented Dickey-Fuller test, Narayan-Popp test etc.), then you don't test cointegration. ca.jo is used when you test whether your I(1) variables co-move or not.